# Error calling method on NPObject silverlight and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

My problem is the follow:
I execute a silverlight method from javascrript, and don´t works, the error is "Error calling method on NPObject".

when I call the javascript method from the silverlight event this works, but when I call this method from javascript show me the error.

My example code:
In silverlight

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("TestFunction"); // calling javascript function
}

[ScriptableMember]
public void CallJS()
{
//Code...
}

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("JS", new MainPage());
   this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
}
```

in javascript:

```
function TestFunction() {
var slObject = document.getElementById("idControl");
slObject.Content.JS.CallJS();
}
```

thanks for any help!

sorry for my english, if someone corrects the wording thank you.